JPA query for json column search
{
   "store_ids":[
      {
         "name":"Gupta General store",
         "store_id":"SSC10000020"
      },
      {
         "name":"Gupta General store2",
         "store_id":"SSC10000022"
      }
   ]
}

This is json object in mysql table column I need a jpa query wherel i want to extract all rows of table where "store_id" is match within the given list of string
@Query("SELECT m FROM MerchantManager m WHERE (JSON_EXTRACT(m, '$.store_ids.store_id') IN ('SSC10000020','SSC10000022'))")
    List<MerchantManager> findByStoreId();

I want to get how will i write this query in spring boot

Which MySQL version are you using?

For a single value search in the entire JSON array for all rows, you can search like this:
@Query(value = "SELECT * from MerchantManager where JSON_CONTAINS(JSON_EXTRACT( columnName, '$.store_ids[*].store_id'), '\"SSC10000020\"')",nativeQuery = true)

But if you want to search multiple values, you need to use the OR operator for the JSON_CONTAINS function.
@Query(value = "SELECT * from MerchantManager where JSON_CONTAINS(JSON_EXTRACT( columnName, '$.store_ids[*].store_id'), '\"SSC10000020\"' OR JSON_CONTAINS(JSON_EXTRACT( columnName, '$.store_ids[*].store_id'), '\"SSC10000022\"')",nativeQuery = true)

There might be other efficient ways with IN operator, but i am not aware of it. I hope this helps.
